# setting the line pattern using CIMG for c++

Tags: c++, cimg

I am trying to learn [Cimg](http://cimg.eu/) but simetimes the documentation is very vague.
I am playing with the drawing functions and I want to draw a line. the functoon declaration is very simple:

```
CImg<T>& draw_line  (   const int   x0,
        const int   y0,
        const int   x1,
        const int   y1,
        const tc *const     color,
        const float     opacity = 1,
        const unsigned int      pattern = ~0U,
        const bool      init_hatch = true 
    )
```

where

```
x0  X-coordinate of the starting line point. 
y0  Y-coordinate of the starting line point.
x1  X-coordinate of the ending line point.
y1  Y-coordinate of the ending line point.
color   Pointer to spectrum() consecutive values of type T, defining    the drawing color.
opacity Drawing opacity.
**pattern   An integer whose bits describe the line pattern.**
init_hatch  Tells if a reinitialization of the hash state must be done.
```

My question is with pattern, I haven't been able to find in the documentation which integers represent which kind of lines. Does anyone now how to manipulate the pattern?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the developers responded this question to me via e-mail, I post it here for anyone who has the same question.

> The pattern is given by how the bits in the unsigned int are sets.
>   You have to look at your unsigned integer as a pattern of 32 pixels (i.e.
>   32bits) that can be either transparent (bit set to 0) or opaque (bit set
>    to 1).
>   For instance, a pattern where all bits are set to 1 is full opaque, and 
>   corresponds to pattern value 0xFFFFFFFF.
>   A pattern where 8 pixels are transparent, then 8 pixels are opaque 
>   corresponds to pattern 0xFF00FF00.
>   A pattern like 0xCCCCCCCC means 1 pixel transparent, then 1 pixel opaque, 
>   etc...